# Did the apostles think that the end is imminent?

Tags: paul, james, peter

Paul:

- Romans 13:11-12.
- 1 Corinthians 7:29.
- 1 Thessalonians 4:15.
- Hebrews 10:37.

James:

- James 5:8.

Peter:

- 1 Peter 4:7.

The question is so simple:

Did the apostles think that the end is imminent?

Comment: So refreshing to see a simple question simply answered about the imminent 'end' - of all things created - by the return of the Lord Jesus; rather than complicated schemes which put his real return (the final judgment) far off. But the next question might be - What happens (immediately) upon the return of Christ ? +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "yes" but there is much more direct evidence of this.  The writers of the NT believed they lived in the "last days", or "last hour".  Note the following:

- Acts 2:17 – Peter calls the day of Pentecost the “last day” in fulfilment of the prophecy of Joel.  Compare v29-32.
- 2 Tim 3:1 – perilous times in the “last day” which Paul discusses as already at his time.
- Heb 1:2 – “These last days” God is revealed in Jesus.
- James 5:3 – warning against rampant materialism and worship of money in the “last day”, that is, the time of James himself.
- 1 Peter 1:5 – Christians reveal God and are miraculously preserved in the “last time”.
- 1 Peter 1:20 – Jesus revealed in these “last times”.
- 2 Peter 3:3 – Peter writes about his time as the fulfilment of that spoken by the ancient prophets about the “last days”.
- 1 John 2:18 – Twice, John calls his time the “last hour”.
- Jude 18 – Jude describes his time as the fulfilment of ancient prophecies about the “last time”.
- Rev 2:16, 3:11, 22:7, 12, 20 – Jesus says, “I am coming soon/quickly”.

Even in Jesus last sermon to the masses, He said that the generation of people that He was talking to, "this generation", would not pass until all things have been fulfilled, Matt 24:34, Mark 13:30, Luke 21:32.  This statement immediately follows the prediction that, "*At that time the sign of the Son of Man will appear in heaven, and all the tribes of the earth will mourn. They will see the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven, with power and great glory. And He will send out His angels with a loud trumpet call, and they will gather His elect from the four winds, from one end of the heavens to the other*." (Matt 24:30-31)

Comment: You perform a real service to this site. Thank you. +1.